# Rails - how to make "Hello, Rails" appear on a web browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am coding my first Rails app by following the tutorial on
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

So far good..  the app (called 'blog') is created and I edited the view

`html.erb` file by typing `<h1>Hello, Rails</1>`

Now I have to edit the routes.rb file by uncommenting the line
containing 'root'. The result should be:

```
root "welcome#index"
```

but when I type `http://localhost:3000`

I get the following error message:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:3000

Did you mean: localhost3000.­org
```

Here are the codes in the `routes.rb` file. Any help will be
appreciated!

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"

    root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: Use `rails server` to start your application, or `rails s` for short.

Comment: note that `<h1>Hello, Rails</1>` is wrong (you need to add an `h` between `/` and `1`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably didn't start the server.

type `rails s` to start a server on localhost:3000

Answer (score 2):

you need to do the following:

```
rails g controller Welcome index
rails s
```

then you have access to your localhost:3000 on your browser